# Help for tangent

Tags: trigonometry

Is this equality correct? how can I get to it starting from the trigonometry basics?

$$tan(\alphaº/2)=\frac{\sqrt{1+tan²(\alpha)}-1}{tan(\alpha)}$$

where $\alpha$ is an angle

Comment: "Another" implies you're familiar with other half-angle identities for tangent -- namely, $\tan(\alpha/2) = \frac{1 - \cos \alpha}{\sin \alpha}$?

Comment: The surd needs a $-$ sign if $\sec\alpha<0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\tan \frac {\alpha}{2} \\
\frac {\sin \frac {\alpha}{2}}{\cos \frac {\alpha}{2}}\\
\frac {\sqrt {1-\cos\alpha}}{\sqrt {1+\cos\alpha}}\\
\frac {(\sqrt {1-\cos\alpha})^2}{\sqrt {1-\cos^2\alpha}}\\
\frac {1-\cos\alpha}{\sin \alpha}\\
\frac {\sec\alpha-1}{\tan \alpha}\\
\frac {\sqrt {1+\tan^2\alpha}-1}{\tan \alpha}\\
$

But I played a little bit fast and loose with the trig there.

In particular $\sec\alpha = \sqrt {1+\tan^2\alpha}$ only when $\sec \alpha \ge 0$

And this identity is not true if $\alpha \in (\frac {\pi}{2}, \frac {3\pi}{2})$

Answer (score 1):

From the tangent double angle formula we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\tan \alpha =\frac{ \tan( \alpha/2)}{1- \tan^2 (\alpha/2)}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Let $T=\tan \alpha$ and $t = \tan( \alpha/2)$
\begin{eqnarray*}
Tt^2+2t-T=0.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now solve this as a quadratic in $t$ and your formula follows.

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{\sqrt{1+\tan^2 \alpha}-1}{\tan \alpha}  $$

> $\sqrt{1+\tan^2\alpha}= \sec\alpha \space \forall \alpha \notin \left({\dfrac{\pi}{2}, {\dfrac{3\pi}{2}}}\right)$

$$\\= \dfrac{\sec\alpha-1}{\tan \alpha}\\= \dfrac{1-\cos\alpha}{\sin \alpha }\\$$Now use [half angle identitities,](http://www.sosmath.com/trig/douangl/douangl.html)$$=\dfrac{1-{( 1- 2\sin^2\alpha/2)}}{2\sin \left(\dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right)\cos \left(\dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right)}\\= \color{blue}{\tan \alpha /2}$$